# Let CentOS 7 on live-USB won't reset to default settings after reboot

Tags: centos, live-usb, persistence

I've downloaded the `LiveGNOME` iso for `CentOS 7` and use [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to make CentOS 7 Live-USB that I can boot a Centos 7 with it.

But after I boot it I've set up some settings, then I shut down it, later I boot it again, and I found out **all the settings and data are reset ** I can't believe it, so I redo the settings and chose restart option, but surprisingly, it resets again.

I've tried to found document with the keyword `centos 7 live-usb save settings` but I can found nothing, only thing I found is with the same case but on Ubuntu you can use `persistence mode (even I don't know what is it)` but can't figure or found documents that tells you how to do it on CentOS 7.

So how can I let the CentOS 7 on my USB (it's installed on USB, not iso on USB to install centos on PC) save settings and documents I saved on it, and does not reset when it's reboot?

Comment: The "live" media is designed to not have persistent changes across boots. If you want changes to be persistent, you will need to install the "full" version on the USB stick.

Comment: @RamanSailopal then if I install `full` version should I just drop the iso on USB or still use `Rufus` and will it has to option to boot on it instead of installing to PC?

Comment: If you run off a live CD for example and then plug in the USB, you should be able to install to the USB.

Comment: How? I've tried to put the everything iso into USB with Rufus but after booting on it it shows installing CentOS which I think it'll install to PC instead of the start CentOS view which I've seen on LiveGNOME iso

Comment: I think the method in Rufus to create a persistent live system works only with Ubuntu and Debian iso files (and some other linux distros with similar boot configurations). Centos uses another kind of boot system so you need another tool or method.

Answer (score 1):

I could suggest you making a bootable usb with persistent storage as compared to what you trying to achieve here.

This of course allow to start a PC with Centos and even you can save whatever your doing there. Once it reboots, yes you will have that worked files after all.

1. first login to a Centos install pc.
2. Lets install required packages;

   - `# yum install -y epel-release`
   - `# yum install livecd-tools syslinux`
3. Insert the USB thumb & mark its partition as bootable(replace the X with your usb);

   > `# parted /dev/sdX`
   >
   > `[parted] toggle 1 boot`
   >
   > `[parted] quit`
4. Now you can create your Centos bootable usb with persistent storage

   - `# livecd-iso-to-disk --home-size-mb 500 CentOS-7.0-x64_84-LiveCD.iso /dev/sdX1`

Thats it.. Now you can use the usb and run it with installed Centos version with persistant storage.

Comment: Can the following process works? `Boot with live-USB (which will reset) -> run the commands -> install centos 7 (which won't reset) to another USB`?

Comment: No, it won't work. If you boot Live-usb, yet it is a non-persistent storage, so you can install permanent Centos there.

Above, what my solution is create the same Live-USB with "persistent storage"

Comment: so I must either use VM or a CentOS installed on PC in order to use above step to create a live-USB that won't reset right?

Comment: yes, you got to do it

Comment: But it seems the centos can't found the USB, I'm running centos on VM, while my USB has 128GB storage and was formatted in exFAT, I don't know why everytime I plug it in **While in the VM tab**, the windows get to read it first, and centos can't read it? How can this be solved?